# Adding a legend with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

I'd like to place the following text in a horizontal legend in a box under these two plots (replacing the text on the left side of (:) with the corresponding shape):

right or down arrow: go forward; left or up arrow: go up; self-loop: stay; red circle: Yes; blue circle: No; half blue, half red circle: Both

How to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, backgrounds,calc,shapes}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle split part fill/.style args={#1,#2}{%
 alias=tmp@name, 
  postaction={%
    insert path={
     \pgfextra{%
     \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{center}}%
                  {\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{east}}%
     \pgfmathsetmacro\insiderad{\pgf@x}
      \fill[#1] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.east) arc
                          (0:180:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;
      \fill[#2] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.west)  arc
                           (180:360:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;            %  \end{scope}
         }}}}}
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
\definecolor{yes}{RGB}{255,51,76}
\definecolor{no}{RGB}{161,251,251}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikzset{shorten >=1pt,
        node distance=.55cm,
        font = \tiny,
        auto,%on grid
        state/.style = {shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+1.7ex,minimum height=+1.4ex,inner sep=+.1pt}
        }
  \subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, fill=gray] (d31) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,above of=d31] (d21) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray, above of=d21] (d11) {};

    \node[state,fill=gray, right of=d11] (d12) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d12] (d22) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d22] (d32) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d32] (d42) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d31] (d41) {};

    \node[state,right of=d12] (d13) {};
    \node[state,right of=d22] (d23) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d32] (d33) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d33] (d43) {};


    \node[state,right of=d13] (d14) {};
    \node[state,right of=d14] (d15) {};
    \node[state,right of=d23] (d24) {};
    \node[state,fill=no,right of=d24] (d25) {};
   \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d33] (d34) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d34] (d35) {};
    \node[state,fill=yes,below of=d34] (d44) {};
    \node[state,right of=d44] (d45) {};

    \path[->,thick] (d25) edge [in=150,out=110,loop] coordinate[pos=0.52] (midp) (d25);
    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (d43) edge node {}(d44);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
        \hspace{.5cm}
    \subfloat[cohort 11]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, fill=gray] (d31) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,above of=d31] (d21) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray, above of=d21] (d11) {};

    \node[state,fill=gray, right of=d11] (d12) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d12] (d22) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d22] (d32) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d32] (d42) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d31] (d41) {};

    \node[state,right of=d12] (d13) {};
    \node[state,right of=d22] (d23) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d32] (d33) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d33] (d43) {};


    \node[state,right of=d13] (d14) {};
    \node[state,right of=d14] (d15) {};
    \node[state,right of=d23] (d24) {};
    \node[state,right of=d24] (d25) {};
   \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d33] (d34) {};
    \node[state,right of=d34] (d35) {};
    \node[state,circle split part fill={no,yes},
    below of=d34] (d44) {};
    \node[state,right of=d44] (d45) {};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (d34) edge node {}(d44)
    (d43) edge node {}(d44);
    \end{tikzpicture}} 
\caption{my figure}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal damage proposal for the legend is to use a matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, backgrounds,calc,shapes}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle split part fill/.style args={#1,#2}{%
 alias=tmp@name, 
  postaction={%
    insert path={
     \pgfextra{%
     \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{center}}%
                  {\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{east}}%
     \pgfmathsetmacro\insiderad{\pgf@x}
      \fill[#1] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.east) arc
                          (0:180:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;
      \fill[#2] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.west)  arc
                           (180:360:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;            %  \end{scope}
         }}}}}
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
\definecolor{yes}{RGB}{255,51,76}
\definecolor{no}{RGB}{161,251,251}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikzset{shorten >=1pt,
        node distance=.55cm,
        font = \tiny,
        auto,%on grid
        state/.style = {shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+1.7ex,minimum height=+1.4ex,inner sep=+.1pt}
        }
  \subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, fill=gray] (d31) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,above of=d31] (d21) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray, above of=d21] (d11) {};

    \node[state,fill=gray, right of=d11] (d12) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d12] (d22) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d22] (d32) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d32] (d42) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d31] (d41) {};

    \node[state,right of=d12] (d13) {};
    \node[state,right of=d22] (d23) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d32] (d33) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d33] (d43) {};


    \node[state,right of=d13] (d14) {};
    \node[state,right of=d14] (d15) {};
    \node[state,right of=d23] (d24) {};
    \node[state,fill=no,right of=d24] (d25) {};
   \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d33] (d34) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d34] (d35) {};
    \node[state,fill=yes,below of=d34] (d44) {};
    \node[state,right of=d44] (d45) {};

    \path[->,thick] (d25) edge [in=150,out=110,loop] coordinate[pos=0.52] (midp) (d25);
    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (d43) edge node {}(d44);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
        \hspace{.5cm}
    \subfloat[cohort 11]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state, fill=gray] (d31) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,above of=d31] (d21) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray, above of=d21] (d11) {};

    \node[state,fill=gray, right of=d11] (d12) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d12] (d22) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d22] (d32) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d32] (d42) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d31] (d41) {};

    \node[state,right of=d12] (d13) {};
    \node[state,right of=d22] (d23) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d32] (d33) {};
    \node[state,fill=gray,below of=d33] (d43) {};


    \node[state,right of=d13] (d14) {};
    \node[state,right of=d14] (d15) {};
    \node[state,right of=d23] (d24) {};
    \node[state,right of=d24] (d25) {};
   \node[state,fill=gray,right of=d33] (d34) {};
    \node[state,right of=d34] (d35) {};
    \node[state,circle split part fill={no,yes},
    below of=d34] (d44) {};
    \node[state,right of=d44] (d45) {};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (d34) edge node {}(d44)
    (d43) edge node {}(d44);
    \end{tikzpicture}} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}% note that \tiny gets inherited from above
\matrix[column sep=1ex]{ \draw[->] (-1.2em,1em) -- (-1.2em,0); \draw[->] (-1em,0.5em) -- (0,0.5em)
node[right] {go forward};
 & 
 \draw[<-] (-1.2em,1em) -- (-1.2em,0); \draw[<-] (-1em,0.5em) -- (0,0.5em)
node[right] {go up}; 
& \draw (-0.2em,0)  edge [in=110,out=70,loop] (-0.2em,0);
\path (0,0.5em) node[right] {stay};
& \path (0,0.5em) node[state,fill=yes,label=right:Yes]{};
& \path (0,0.5em) node[state,fill=no,label=right:No]{};
& \path (0,0.5em) node[state,circle split part fill={no,yes},label=right:Both]{};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\caption{my figure}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I was you I would also draw the main diagrams as matrices, and trade the `\pgfextra` stuff for simple `path picture`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,matrix}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{yes}{RGB}{255,51,76}
\definecolor{no}{RGB}{161,251,251}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikzset{semifill/.style 2 args={path picture={
        \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.west) rectangle
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.west) rectangle
            (path picture bounding box.south east);
             }},
        shorten >=1pt,
        node distance=.55cm,
        font = \tiny,
        auto,%on grid
        state/.style = {shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+1.7ex,minimum height=+1.4ex,inner sep=+.1pt}
        }
  \subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={state},
        column sep=1em,row sep=1em,yshift=4cm,
        column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        row 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        row 4/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        ampersand replacement=\&] (mat) {
      \& \&  \& \& \\ 
      \& \& \& \& |[fill=no]|\\ 
      \& \& \& \& \\ 
      \& \& \& |[fill=yes]| \& |[fill=white]|\\      
     };
    \path[->,thick] (mat-2-5) edge [in=150,out=110,loop] (mat-2-5);
    \draw[->,thick] (mat-4-3) -- (mat-4-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
        \hspace{.5cm}
    \subfloat[cohort 11]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={state},
        column sep=1em,row sep=1em,
        column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        row 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        row 4/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        ampersand replacement=\&] (mat) {
      \& \&  \& \& \\ 
      \& \& \& \& \\ 
      \& \& \& \&  |[fill=white]|\\ 
      \& \& \& |[semifill={no}{yes}]| \& |[fill=white]|\\    
     };
    \draw[->,thick] (mat-4-3) -- (mat-4-4);
    \draw[->,thick] (mat-3-4) -- (mat-4-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}% note that \tiny gets inherited from above
\matrix[column sep=1ex]{ \draw[->] (-1.2em,1em) -- (-1.2em,0); \draw[->] (-1em,0.5em) -- (0,0.5em)
node[right] {go forward};
 & 
 \draw[<-] (-1.2em,1em) -- (-1.2em,0); \draw[<-] (-1em,0.5em) -- (0,0.5em)
node[right] {go up}; 
& \draw (-0.2em,0)  edge [in=110,out=70,loop] (-0.2em,0);
\path (0,0.5em) node[right] {stay};
& \path (0,0.5em) node[state,fill=yes,label=right:Yes]{};
& \path (0,0.5em) node[state,fill=no,label=right:No]{};
& \path (0,0.5em) node[state,semifill={no}{yes},label=right:Both]{};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\caption{my figure.}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you put the legend in a box(rectangle)?

Comment: @ie86 Just replace `\matrix[column sep=1ex]` by `\matrix[column sep=1ex,draw]`.

Comment: I wanted to add the white node and gray node to the legend but it will exceed the margin so I need to use  \\ after the red circle and go to the second row but then the space between these items gets messed up and changing the value of "sep" doesn't work at all. How should I do that?

Comment: @ie86 From your description it is next-to-impossible to really see what you have done. Can you show an explicit code, preferably in form of a new question?

Comment: Here it is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/535717/legend-with-tikz